# LINUX msgget and queue

Tags: linux, memory

I have simple code:

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdlib.h>
  3 #include <errno.h>
  4 #include <string.h>
  5 #include <sys/types.h>
  6 #include <sys/ipc.h>
  7 #include <sys/msg.h>
  8
  9 struct my_msgbuf {
 10     long mtype;
 11     char mtext[200];
 12 };
 13
 14 int main(void){
 15     struct my_msgbuf buf;
 16     int msqid;
 17     key_t key;
 18
 19     if((key = ftok("main.c", 'B')) == -1) {
 20         perror("ftok"); exit(1);
 21     }
 22
 23     if( (msqid = msgget(key, 0644 | IPC_CREAT)) == -1){
 24         perror("msgget");
 25         exit(1);
 26     }
 27
 28     printf("Enter lines of text, ^D to quit:\n");
 29     buf.mtype = 1;
 30     while(fgets(buf.mtext, sizeof(buf.mtext), stdin) != NULL){
 31         int len = strlen(buf.mtext);
 32         if(buf.mtext[len-1] == '\n') buf.mtext[len-1] = '\0';
 33         if(msgsnd(msqid, &buf, len+1,0) == -1){
 34             perror("msgsnd");
 35         }
 36
 37     }
 38
 39     if(msgctl(msqid, IPC_RMID, NULL) == -1){
 40         perror("msgctl");
 41         exit(1);
 42     }
 43
 44  return 0;
 45 }
```

and next step what i do:

```
gcc -o main main.c
```

next step run:

```
./main
```

and results:

msgget: no space left on device

how can I repair it? I'm working on university server (connecting by putty), it can be answer about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page, `ENOSPC` is the error for:

> A message queue has to be created but the system limit for the  maximum number of message queues (MSGMNI) would be exceeded.

If it's a server, it means there's too many message queues created by other users (not unlikely if this is some homework assignment and other students also work on the server). You can see the MSGMNI value with `cat /proc/sys/kernel/msgmni`. Only the admin can change it however.